# Facebook WebDialog Login and key hash security

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication

In the Facebook for Android SDK 3.0, when you use a WebDialog to authenticate users (via `SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO`), it does not authenticate against the Key Hashes defined in the Facebook app settings. It seems that the Key Hashes are only checked when logging in using the Android native Facebook app.

As a test I removed all Key Hashes and put the Facebook app in production mode. Logging in via native login gives me an error as expected, but logging in via WebDialog is successful.

Doesn't this mean that you can specify someone else's Facebook app ID and perform functions as that app? For example, I changed the `app_id` in my Android app to `107092686086560` (Coke Zone Facebook app). And when I login using WebDialog it will let me login and post to my friends walls via Coke Zone. Isn't this a security issue?

Comment: Thats look really weird, have you try to restarted you android phone and mac?

Comment: It's not considered a security issue because when the user signs in via the web dialog and authorizes your app, they will see both the icon and the name of the app, and presumably would know if they tried to sign in from the Pepsi app, but the icon now says Coke.

Comment: @MingLi the security issue is that the Facebook web dialog allows you to connect to any Facebook app. It is a bit flimsy to rely on the user to check the app details e.g. if the user isn't paying much attention and approves the app. Why can't the web dialog enforce key hash checks?

Comment: The web dialog cannot enforce the checking because it relies on the client to send the correct hash key. Since the "client" is embedded in the app, and it's open source, it's trivial to change the code and send a different hash key to the web dialog.

Comment: Thanks. I can see for SSO it sends an Intent with the app id to the native Facebook app. For my understanding, can you explain how the native Facebook app performs the key hash authentication from this step?